# Stored procedure name changed during execution using Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-data

I need to call an Oracle stored procedure using Spring annotation `@Procedure` in my Repository as follows:

```
    @Procedure(name = "SECURITE.P_MAJ_DROITFAM")
    public void updateDroitFamille (@Param("v_id_fam") Long idFamille,@Param("v_action_type") Integer cas,@Param("v_user") String userName);
```

**Error log** :

> *Hibernate: {call **updateDroitFamille** (?,?,?)}    15: 46: 39,946 - ERROR - SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions: 146 - ORA-06550: Line 1,
>   column 7: PLS-00201: The identifier 'UPDATEDROITFAMILLE' must be
>   declared*

but procedure name is **P_MAJ_DROITFAM** and not **updateDroitFamille**
The problem is that the procedure name has been changed during execution!!? any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is put additional configuration on one of your entities do declare the definition of your procedure first in the application:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "P_MAJ_DROITFAM", procedureName = "SECURITE.P_MAJ_DROITFAM", parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "v_id_fam", type = Long.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = ""v_action_type", type = Integer.class) },
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = ""v_user", type = Integer.class) })
public class MyEntity{
```

Then in the repository you would call like:

```
@Procedure(name = "P_MAJ_DROITFAM")
    public void updateDroitFamille (@Param("v_id_fam") Long idFamille,@Param("v_action_type") Integer cas,@Param("v_user") String userName);
```

You can keep the name of the method.